# TikZ: using filldraw with the let in syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I get `\filldraw` to fill the wedge when I use `\filldraw let .. in` syntax?

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[inner color = blue!50!, outer color = blue!10!black] let
    \p0 = (0, 0),
    \p1 = (1, 0),
    \p2 = (.707, .707),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1cm}
  in (0, 0) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I would like to achieve is this:

[image]

where `\filldraw` was used in this manner:

```
\filldraw[inner color = blue!50!, outer color = blue!10!black] (2.5, 0) --
  +(.5, 0) arc (0:35.2644:.5cm);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `--` to build a path (I changed the scale just for the example):

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \filldraw[inner color = blue!50!, outer color = blue!10!black] let
    \p0 = (0, 0),
    \p1 = (1, 0),
    \p2 = (.707, .707),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1cm}
  in (\p0) -- +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When filling (filldrawing), I always prefer to use `-- cycle` at the end of the path, as in:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \filldraw[inner color = blue!50!, outer color = blue!10!black] let
    \p0 = (0, 0),
    \p1 = (1, 0),
    \p2 = (.707, .707),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {1cm}
  in (\p0) -- +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer.

Comment: @dustin I don't understand your second question; this works without the `let` syntax (the value for the end angle was approximated): `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\node at (0,0) {A};
\node at (1,0) {B};
\node at (0.707,0.707) {C};
  \filldraw[inner color = blue!50!, outer color = blue!10!black]
   (0,0) -- +(1,0) arc[radius = 1, start angle = 0, end angle = 40] -- (0.707,0.707) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Why did `\filldraw` color in the wedge, but when `\filldraw` was used in conjunction with the `let in` syntax, we needed to specify another point and tell it to cycle?

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer; I was in a hurry when I first answered. The real problem was that you were not really building a path with your original code. This explains the difference you asked for in your previous comment.